# Not getting/setting the right return value in a bool function

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, ios8

This is my below swift code. By default the `success` variable is set to false. From the looks of it the `success` variable is never getting updated inside the object. Hence the return value is always false. Any hints on how should I go about solving this?

UPDATE: I added the `println` to see if the logic is going through and it is.

```
class Auth {
    func authUser(email: String, password: String) {
        var success : Bool = false
        let parameters = [
            "user1": [
                "adminEmail": email,
                "adminPassword": password
            ]
        ]
        var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        Alamofire.request(.POST, loginURL, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (_, _, object, error) -> Void in
            if(object != nil) {
                if(JSON(object!)["success"].asBool == true) {
                   println("user signed in")
                   self.authSuccess()
                }
            }
        }

    }

func authSuccess() -> Bool {
    self.success = true
    println(success) // this does not get printed out.
    return success
}
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func signInButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var auth = Auth()
    auth.authUser(emailTxtField.text, password: pwdTxtField.text)
    println(auth.success)
}
```

Just starting out with swift. So any pointers are helpful.

Comment: If it is never being set to true, then that means that you're not getting through one of your `if` statements. Add a `println` to in the body of your first one to figure out which one and try to figure out how to fix it from there.

Comment: I did add a println and it is going through it. The authentication is successful on the backend too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Alamofire request completes asynchronously - executing the closure once the request has completed, however by this time the `authUser` method has already returned, with the value `false`.

It isn't possible for `authUser` to return success/fail - you need to invoke another method from the closure to handle the success/fail

You don't need to check the `auth` flag in order to update the label (although you might want to use that property elsewhere in your app, that is fine).  When `authSuccess` is called you can simply update the label.  You need to dispatch updates to UI elements on the main queue - your `authSuccess` will be executing on a background thread, so use

```
func authSuccess()  {
    self.success = true
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
        self.myLabel="Authenticaton successful"
    }

}
```

You should also handle the other conditions in your closure and call `authFail` or something if it fails in order to update the UI and provide feedback to the user.

Comment: I did that. Updated the code. But looks like that is not getting set too. Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Your code looks correct, but you don't check error and you don't do anything if object is nil. Since you aren't getting your message I suspect that there was an error or nil returned.  You can set a breakpoint in your closure and examine the results

Comment: Right, this is just for testing. But if I set a println message above line at ```self.authSuccess()``` . The line gets printed.

Comment: I have updated the question on how I am checking the value in view controller. Maybe the value setting or calling method is wrong there?

Comment: Ok, so your other problem is that you are creating a local `Auth` object in your IBAction.  As soon as this object goes out of scope (when the IBAction method exits) it will be released - this will happen before the asynchronous authentication completes.  Try moving the `auth` var to a property and using `self.auth`

Comment: Read the first sentence of the answer: You are using in asynchronous call. authSuccess will be called at some point in the future. The authUser call puts the asynchronous call on a queue, where it eventually finishes, but authUser returns immediately. It's clearer if you call the method "startUserAuthentication". It doesn't authenticate, it just triggers the authentication sometime in the future.

Comment: @Paulw11. Got it. Figured out. Thanks much. But I think what gnasher729 mentions, also make sense now. Because, since the call gets in a queue and the variables returns quicker than the call. The boolean gets settled a little late. That is in the second try, I get the message on the screen I want to. Because by the second call, the value of boolean is now updated. Maybe I add a sleep call or show a loader sign?

Comment: When writing mobile apps in general (and definitely with iOS apps) you should think in terms of event-driven programs.  An event - button press - triggers the start of login.  An even - the completion of the login - calls a method that updates the UI/presents a new view etc.  `Sleep` is rarely a good idea.  Providing some feedback to the user that login is progressing is.

Comment: I guess the sleep call won't help. Since the variable is returned quicker than the actual value of boolean being, If I want to show an updated label it gets displayed in the second click of the button.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip, coming from web, this was not obvious to me :).

Comment: @Paulw11 could you give me a pointer on how can I go about checking to see when the value of ```success``` is changed?